# Elasticsearch query identical arrays

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch

I have documents like these:

**Doc1**

```
{
"id": ...,
...
"articles": [
  {
    "id": "5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#142936",
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": "5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#226536",
    ...
  }
...
}
```

**Doc2**

```
{
"id": ...,
...
"articles": [
  {
    "id": "5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#142936",
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": "5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#226536",
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": "5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#142965",
    ...
  }
...
}
```

**Doc3**

```
{
"id": ...,
...
"articles": [
  {
    "id": "5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#142936",
    ...
  }
...
}
```

And I want the document exactly has the array of articles I need. For example, if my Array of article Ids is ['5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#142936', '5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#226536'] I only want to get the Doc1.

Now I have this query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "articles",
            "query": {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "articles.id",
                "query": "5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#142936 AND 5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#226536"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But with this, I get Doc1 & Doc2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `articles.id` is of type `keyword`, I think this should work for you (not sure it's the most efficient way to write the query):

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "articles",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "articles.id": "5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#142936"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "articles",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "articles.id": "5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#226536"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "articles",
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "default_field": "articles.id",
              "query": "NOT 5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#142936 AND NOT 5cdd17c7e24f6e05d487b2c2#226536"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you!